# Funções com ajax fazem loop for parar de ser executado

Tags: javascript, ajax, funções

Tenho uma função que executa quando clico em um botão. Ao clicar, a função deve executar um `loop for` e se o valor daquele posição do contador do `for` corresponder a algum dos `ifs` então ele executa a função. Essas funções são todas chamadas `ajax`.

```
var checkbox_tipos = document.forms[1];

document.getElementById('gerar_dss').addEventListener('click', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    test : for (i = 0; i < checkbox_tipos.length; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        console.log(checkbox_tipos.length);

        if(checkbox_tipos[i].checked){
            console.log(checkbox_tipos[i].value);
            if(checkbox_tipos[i].value === 'dss_chuva'){
                console.log('entrou em chuva');
                dss_chuva();
                continue test;
            }
            if(checkbox_tipos[i].value === 'dss_cota'){
                console.log('entrou em cota');
                dss_cota();
                continue test;
            }
            if(checkbox_tipos[i].value === 'dss_vazao'){
                console.log('entrou em vazao');
                dss_vazao();
                continue test;
            }
        }
    }
});

function dss_vazao(){

    for (i = 0; i < checkbox_estacoes.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox_estacoes[i].checked) {
          estacao[i]=checkbox_estacoes[i].value;
        }
    }

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

            console.log(data.result);
            alert(data.result);
        }
    }

    ajax.open('POST', '../server/gerar-vazoes.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    ajax.send('estacoes='+estacao+'&data_inicio='+data_inicio.value+'&data_fim='+data_fim.value+ 
        '&nome_arquivo='+nome_arquivo.value+'&observacao='+observacao.value+'&tipo='+tipo.value);
}
```

Fazendo testes, percebi que ao executar uma das funções o `for` para de rodar e, assim, não percorre continua com o `loop`. Procurando por aí vi o `statemt` "continue" e tentei aplicar mas não funcionou. O problema é: como fazer ele continuar? Desde já agradeço!

[EDIT 1]: Para melhor entendimento: o problema é que quando, no `for`, entra em uma das condições `if` e executa uma das funções o `for` não continua o `loop`. Exemplo: o `for` deveria rodar 3 vezes, mas na primeira volta do `loop` ao entrar em um dos `if`s ele não continua as duas voltas que deveria fazer, como se o `for` fosse encerrado.

Comment: Eu não entendi perfeitamente seu problema, mas algum tempo atrás eu tive problemas com várias requisições sendo feitas dentro de um for. A minha dúvida foi essa: [Como esperar até que todas as requisições terminem?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346752/como-esperar-at%C3%A9-que-todas-as-requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-terminem)

Comment: @Marconi obrigado. Fiz um edit, vê se dá pra entender melhor.

Comment: @Ramones ainda não ficou muito claro :/ ,mas você poderia passar o código completo no github ou algo assim e nos descrever os passos para entender o problema ? E sobre essas requisições Ajax recomendo fortemente o uso do JQuery em vez do XMLHttpRequest diretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema ao identificar que no `for` não havia o `var` na variável que serve de contador. Ao inserir o `var` funcionou como esperado.